# how can I reduce the vertical space between divs

Tags: css, html

Hi I have  a problem with the distance between divs on a page, as I need to insert more divs (names) without changing my layout.
http://www.galeriedenandel.nl/Assets/PageDesigns/kunstenaars.html
I have tried to find an answer on the web but have had no luck.
As the divs are also a menu I need to have the vertical distance between them reduced by one half to two thirds.
I have tried everything that I know plus a lot of just playing around, but nothing seems to work. Could some one ( if it is of interest to any one ) please have a look and give me some advice on how to fix the problem.
Than you Steven

Comment: Which divs are you referring to? The menu is fine and the vertical spacing between menu items is done within `#menu a { margin-right: 5px; }` Divs by default have no spacing at all, only what you've added.

Comment: don't really know if I should be ansereing your question here or not .I want to move the divs closer together so ibasically wat to close the distanse between the name, the thing works fine but i am frightened that if I place more names in that it will push the bottom of the page below the viewable page, this is the first site that I have ever made and am not so knowledgeable abot the effects it will have on the appeatance of the site

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, still not sure what div(s) you're referring to. The thing with HTML / CSS is that you'll learn best from trial + error. Have a play around if you know which elements you need to modify, and see how it works for you. Remember to ensure it works cross-browser ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The vertical spacing (between the names) seems to come from the margin-attribute of the "H4"Tag. There is no div-tag involved. So just adjust that H4-tag to have a smaller margin. (But the use of the H4-Tag at that position is not semantically correct anyway :) )

Comment: @Philip HornThanks philip when I remove the H4 tag The distance Closes so you are right that that is where the problem lays, but then it is to close to the previous name .

Comment: @Philip HornAny way that I can put a couple of pixels of space between?

Comment: You could leave the H4 and just set a margin that seems right to you. At the moment the H4 doesn't have any styles except the ones from the default user-stylesheets (the settings in each user's browser - which is a margin of 1.33em in my case). The H4s already have a class so you can easily change their margin in your stylesheet.

Comment: @philipp horn Or can it close up if I were to use something else as a tag , or do I need to add padding in the css? and if so where?

Comment: @philipp Horn Thanks phillip just added this to the style sheet ( #content_wrap #artists h4{ margin-bottom:2px; } ) but it doesn't do any thing , not quite sure what you mean by increasing the margin?

Comment: With the H4s your texts can get as close together as with any other tag :) You just need to explicitly tell the H4 in your stylesheet how much margin it should have (i.e. h4.artists { margin:1em 0; } ) Here's a good link on CSS/HTML: http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: @steven "#artists h4" won't work for diffenrent reasons...you have a H4 with a class of "artists". To style that element you need "h4.artists". (a "." means class, a "#" means id in CSS)

Comment: @Phillip Horn Thanks  Philipp that is hopefully where I can pick up a bit more info I used them to begin to understand HTML when I started to Write the site, the CSS I just learned through tutorial on uyou tube and trial and error, I did not have a H4 element in my css sheet

Comment: @steven You're welcome! CSS is very powerful and you definitely don't want to miss out on it's features for creating webpages (and it's not that complicated once you've messed around with it a bit :) ) Oh and feel free to accept my answer if it helped ;)

Comment: @PhilippHorn Thanks philipp I will use the info I just have to figure out how to write the CSs tag for the H4 so that it works correectly, I also am so pleased with the power of CSS, I used it for the first time to write the site , caused me alot of pain and grief but I love what it can do , I feel also the same about iframes, absolutly wonderfull stuff if you can get your head around it, but sometimes it's hard to see the forrest for the trees ( I mean that I get so involved with what I am doing that I find it difficult some times to find the right way to go with the script

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ul li` instead of `h4`.